# Pagination with lookup index in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination with the ability to jump to different pages depending on the item the user clicks on.

For example I have a list of items in a paginated table on the right side of the screen and ***all*** items displayed on the map on the left side of the screen. The user clicks on an item on the left and it automatically moves the view on the right to the page that has this item

I have no idea how to start implementing something like this, I thought about making 2 different requests for each view but there is no way to maintain coupling between the 2 views

I am thinking page based pagination but struggling with figuring out how to maintain the pointers.

Does anyone have hints on where to start with implementing this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for pagination

pagination.py

```
from rest_framework import pagination

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'path.core.pagination.CustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

views

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def list(self, request):
        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```